# GDAL >= 2.2.x on Mac OS with Python bindings

Tags: gdal, mac, python-2

I'm needing to use the `Python` binding of `GDAL >= 2.2.x` in a `Mac OS` environment. Kyngchaos most recent binaries are provided for version `2.1.3`. Out of compiling from source, is there any other option for install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [conda-forge packages](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal)? They do have 2.2.1, and are available for MacOSX, Windows and Linux. You need to install anaconda to use them though.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing with Homebrew from the [OSGeo Homebrew Tap](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac). You can then use `brew install gdal2-python` to install the GDAL2 Python bindings.